# Application of non-galoisian Galois theory

Tags: galois-theory

In the seventh chapter of "Galois Theories" by Borceux and Janelidze, we proved non-galoisian Galois theory, and Joyal-Tierney theorem is introduced as one of the applications of the theory. Is there any papers or books which contains some applications of non-galoisian Galois theory?

Comment: See [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144708/janelidzes-galois-theory).

Comment: Thank you for your help!